# blocking all mapping drives and direct shared access programmatically

Tags: c#, mapped-drive

Due to the nature of the project, I am assigned to implement a stand-alone C# application to block all mapped network drives as well as direct shared access. The requirement needs to have only one way in and one way out.  That way, the Sys Admin will control the data coming in and out.  I could not think of a way to accomplish this task.

For all mapped drives, it is advised that "Group policy" would be able to manage it.  However, a user can access directly to the share using `\\ExternalServerName\anyfolder\` in the command line.

Is there a way to block these direct share programmatically?

Any guidance, article related to this type of topic is much appreciated.

Thanks

JPL

Comment: This isn't a C# question, it has nothing to do with C#. If you want to block access from a specific machine to another machine (or all machines), use a firewall.

Comment: Thanks Caesay for your quick response.   The main idea of the application is to manage the auditing log of all actions when users move files in/out.   I guess I need to work with Sys Admin of the server so they can control how the firewall could be set up.   From there, the C# application can manage all the  data transactions.    Much appreciated.

Comment: You would need to use group policies but as @caesay says, this isnt a stack overflow question

Comment: Okay, let me ask you a question... Is all of the access to the drives to be done through your standalone application? If that's the case I have an answer for you. If not, let us know a little more about how the data on the drives gets accessed. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, @snoopy.   The app will manage all of drives. Please share your solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You all are correct.   It is beyond the application itself.   I will setup the kiosk mode in that env and control all from there.
Thanks